# "real part" of complex differential operators on $Sl_{2}(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: complex-analysis, lie-groups, differential-operators

Let $D$ be a complex differential operator on the complex Lie-Group $SL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$. How is the "real part" of $D$ with regards to $SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ defined?
Im currently reading a lecture series by Atiyah about characters of semisimple Lie-Groups and he considers $SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ as a real form of $SL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ to prove certain equalities of differential operators on $SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ by "complexifying" them.

Answer (score 0):

The complex Lie Group $\text{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ can be considered as a six dimensional Lie Group $\text{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}}$ The real and imaginary part are considered as independent real parameters.

The Lie Algebra of $sl_{2}(\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}}$ turns out to be isomorphic to the Lorentz group.

Comment: Hello! I'm sorry but I don't understand how this explains how a "real part" of a complex differential operator on $SL_{2}(\mathbb{C}) is / could be defined.